# Node webkit Install Without Admin Rights

Tags: node-webkit

I have a NW app and I used Enigma Virtual Box to pack it to a single exe file.
This file need admin rights.
Is there any option to pack NW without admin rights for institution users?

Comment: Where does the app install itself? Maybe the work-around could be to have the app install to a user folder instead.